# CentOS 6 - YUM doesn't work - primary.sqlite.bz2 [Error -1] Metadata file does not match checksum

Tags: rpm, centos6, yum, percona

This error doesn't go away until I remove **percona-release-0.1-6.noarch.rpm** from my repository.

*percona-release-noarch/primary_db                                                                                                                         |  972 B     00:00

http://repo.percona.com/release/6/RPMS/noarch/repodata/11d28cdbe574f40a909a59ebad292167baabb433e0366950389952475ddf1184-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno -1] Metadata file does not match checksum
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/11d28cdbe574f40a909a59ebad292167baabb433e0366950389952475ddf1184-primary.sqlite.bz2 from percona-release-noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.*

P.S.
I have tried

yum clean all
yum clean metadata
rm -rf /var/cache/yum/*
rm -rf /var/tmp/yum*

nothing works. Also, removing the repository from using **rpm -e** solves, but I need to install percona tools.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Percona is, but that repository seems to (a) have no mirrors and (b) have their metadata messed up. Nothing you can do from your end, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

disclosure: I am from Percona

We tried to reproduce your problem without success. Perhaps there was a connectivity issue, it's hard to tell. This was what we used:

```
yum install http://www.percona.com/downloads/percona-release/redhat/0.1-6/percona-release-0.1-6.noarch.rpm
```

As you have already removed the package we would suggest that you run

```
sudo yum clean all
```

and then install the package once again using this command

```
yum install http://www.percona.com/downloads/percona-release/redhat/0.1-6/percona-release-0.1-6.noarch.rpm
```

See how you get on.

Comment: I read it somewhere on some blog that this issue goes away automatically. The day I posted this issue, two days after that day, there was no issue in installing anything. So, it works now. But, I feel there is some territory that is unknown. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll pass this back to our devs. If you happen on the blog post do let me have the link. Glad you're working now.